# "Show only contacts with phone number" - Filter missing in Android 4

Tags: contacts, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, filter

The stock contacts app of Android 2.3. *(and older versions)* had a filter that displays only contacts with a phone number, accessible under `Menu -> Display Options -> Only contacts with phones`.

This seems to be gone in android 4. The other display options moved to `Menu -> Settings`, but this one is missing. It's also not under `Menu -> Contacts to display`.

Does anybody know if this option still exists and where it is if thats the case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Ice Cream Sandwich, the old Contacts app was now replaced with the [People app](http://socialtimes.com/android-os-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich-people-app-social-api_b81768). This new app is meant to keep you connected with all of your contacts, not just people you call, and it does so in different ways then the old contacts app, by hooking in to social networks and things like that.

The option to only show contacts with a phone number is not an option in the new People app. But I agree that it should be there, especially when you are searching for a contact when you want to make a phone call.

Answer (score 5):

The new phone App in ICS does have a contacts tab of its own, it seems to show only the contacts with numbers so you might prefer to use that on most occasions.

Comment: Oh you are right. I missed this completely because it's somewhat hidden below the "most contacted" list, but it's there. Will use that, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

The People app shows all the contacts regardless of what information is available. But the dialer app only shows contacts with phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How it works is this:

- If you obtain a contact straight from the menu you will see all contacts, including email addresses

But if you go to Contacts via dialer, you will see only contacts with phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comment found at the top of the relevant source file for the Contacts app in ICS:

> /*TODO(emillar) I commented most of the code that deals with modes and filtering. It should be
>    * brought back in as we add back that functionality.
>    */

So it appears it has been removed temporarily and will be available again in a future version of the contacts app.

Comment: Kudos for going through the source code. @Jeshurun