# Hide contacts with only email address

Tags: contacts

When clicking on Phone -> Logs, I have hundreds of contacts presumably from Gmail.  Is there a way to hide all google contacts, and only show ones I've manually entered (SIM or other storage)? I'd like to only see contacts with phone numbers when using the Phone.

My phone is a S2 (Tmobile), if it matters.

Comment: What Android version are you on? Have you seen [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20066/22822)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not mentioned your Android version, if it is Android 4.0+, I fear you cannot do this. There's no option to show contacts with phone numbers only in `People` app that is included in 4.0+.

If you are on GingerBread or earlier versions, you have a setting something like this:

```
Contacts app - > Menu -> Display Options -> Only contacts with phone numbers
```

I am talking about stock Android apps, your manufacturer / ROM builder may have a tweak depending on what ROM are you running. I don't see a chance, but still a possibility.

See this [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20066/22822).