# Android 4.2 Quick switch between SMS/call/contacts

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, 2.2-froyo

I just changed my phone to an Android 4.2.

I was under 2.2 before.

It takes me quite some time to get confortable with the newest interfaces.
Out of it, I completely miss the possibility to quickly swipe a contact or a text message to call him immediately as shown on those pictures:

[image: Swipe to text]
[image: Swipe to call]

**How can I achieve something similar on Android 4.2? I mean quickly jump from calling to texting to contact easily?**

Until now, it takes me 3 taps to call from text messages, can't achieve to send sms from call log, and since contacts are not filtered in People App (["Show only contacts with phone number" - Filter missing in Android 4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20066/show-only-contacts-with-phone-number-filter-missing-in-android-4)) it takes a while to find people from contacts.

Comment: What phone do you have? Is it skinned (Samsung Touchwiz, HTC Sense, ...etc)? The pictures look like Samsung Touchwiz interface, did you upgrade the phone to a new version or is this a new phone?

Comment: That's a feature on Samsung's dialler, I don't know if any other ones do it, but there are lots of free diallers on the Play Store, worth a look. I assume you installed a non-touchwiz ROM?

Comment: I have a Fairphone http://www.fairphone.com/ now (got a new phone). I think the best option I have is to click on the contact picture now, as described in this post: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29269/how-do-i-add-a-phone-number-to-contacts-from-the-text-message-app
Still 2 clicks but better than nothing!